# How Can I make GIF using arrays

Tags: python, computer-vision, gif

Need some help

I am working with "[moving_mnist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvV9T.png)" dataset. Loading this data using `tfds.load("moving_mnist")` and then convert it in arrays using `tfds.as_numpy()` which will return image sequence arrays of shape (20,64,64,1) where 20 is number of frames. Now what I want, to show these arrays as GIF in my jupyter notebook please see below code which I tried but it will generate simple image for last frame.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds, ds_info = tfds.load("moving_mnist", with_info = True,split="test")

num_examples = 3
examples = list(dataset_utils.as_numpy(ds.take(num_examples)))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3*3, 3*3))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1/3, wspace=1/3)
for i, ex in enumerate(examples):
   video = ex["image-sequence"]
   frame,height, width, c = video.shape

   if c == 1:
       video = video.reshape(video.shape[:3])

       for i in range(0,frame):
       ax.imshow(video[i,:,:], animated=True)
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ufTVng6zQAnyXkg4tMzdwl7toMeI-zbB/view?usp=sharing) is result I got but want it as GIF

Answer (score 2):

The [moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) library makes this pretty easy:

```
import numpy as np
frames = np.random.randint(256, size=[20, 64, 64, 1], dtype=np.uint8)  # YOUR DATA HERE

# save it as a gif
from moviepy.editor import ImageSequenceClip
clip = ImageSequenceClip(list(frames), fps=20)
clip.write_gif('test.gif', fps=20)
```

Then if you want to show that gif in a jupyter notebook, in the next cell you can type:

```
from IPython.display import display, Image
Image('test.gif')
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the library array2gif.

Here is in example taken from the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/array2gif/):

```
import numpy as np
from array2gif import write_gif

dataset = [
    np.array([
        [[255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0]],  # red intensities
        [[0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0]],  # green intensities
        [[0, 0, 255], [0, 0, 255]]   # blue intensities
    ]),
    np.array([
        [[0, 0, 255], [0, 0, 255]],
        [[0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 0]],
        [[255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0]]
    ])
]
write_gif(dataset, 'rgbbgr.gif', fps=5)
```

Comment: Thank you so much just want to confirm is it show results directly on jupyter notebook as I shown in Image link above or is it save it as GIF?

Comment: Its not show results as GIF it is saving in my local directory, can you please have some method to show directly it as GIF or as frame packets not individually frames

Comment: I am not using jupyter notebooks myself but i came across this link maybe it helps you:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10045

Comment: Yes I also come up with it but I want to show results directly rather than saving it but thanks for looking into this

Comment: I don't know a way to load it immediately but storing it in a file and then loading it in jupyter notebook to display it should work. Is there a reason you do not want the file saved? Otherwise I think it is your easiest option.

Comment: Yes you are right it is simple to save and then load but it is unnecessary when I call my method it always first save it and then again read it and then shows it. Which I think take more memory and time. As you can see there are 10000 examples in moving_mnist dataset